# php curl to get xml feed does not return all the data

Tags: php, xml, curl

So I have this private function:

```
private function curl_get($url)
{
    // Initiate the curl session
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Removes the headers from the output
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Return the output instead of displaying it directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    // Execute the curl session
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

And I use if for example with this link: http://www.metacafe.com/api/item/cb-xuFyGC0jJqPfhMoFnewj4Da_ZhHCz4L2/

now the problem is that doesn't return all the data, all I get is this:

```
[data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [version] => 2.0
                    [source] => Metacafe
                )

            [title] => Metacafe
            [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-GKeDVFevZxk_rNri_uz_K01azz3uV_ZZ/
                    [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [url] => http://s.mcstatic.com/Images/MCLogo4RSS.jpg
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com
                            [title] => Metacafe
                            [height] => 65
                            [width] => 229
                        )

                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => cb-GKeDVFevZxk_rNri_uz_K01azz3uV_ZZ
                            [author] => CBS
                            [title] => Romney Concedes South Carolina Primary
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-GKeDVFevZxk_rNri_uz_K01azz3uV_ZZ/romney_concedes_south_carolina_primary/
                            [rank] => 4.00
                            [category] => News & Events
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-GKeDVFevZxk_rNri_uz_K01azz3uV_ZZ/romney_concedes_south_carolina_primary/
                            [pubDate] => 18 hours ago +0000
                        )

                )

        )
```

Why isn't it returning the description and the tags, which are pretty important to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not due to `curl` but how SimpleXml handles CDATA:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($stringFromCurl, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

will interpret the CDATA as text nodes, see the [XML constants on PNP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php)

Comment: oh, didn't know that... I am new to XML and just learned something new thanks to you and also got the solution.

Comment: I guess now all I have to do is preg_match to separate the data (tags, description, submitted by) in  [description], right?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML does have "all the data", it just is not visible via `print_r()`.

```
echo $your_simplexml_object->channel->item->description;
```

Comment: No, it only worked around a "problem". All of the data is sitting right there, just not being shown by `print_r()` (without `LIBXML_NOCDATA`).

Comment: oh I get it, but this kinda makes my problem more difficult because now in order to get only the data I need I have to write some massive `preg_match` when with `LIBXML_NOCDATA` through `DOMDocument` I can make it more accessible the data needed

Comment: Your use of `preg_match()`, `LIBXML_NOCDATA` or `DOMDocument` have no bearing on the fact that you were incorrect in thinking that the SimpleXML object didn't have the `description` contents.

Comment: yes indeed @salathe, yes indeed. Thank you very much for teaching me one more new thing today.